# Iphone authenticated user is not redirected to app

Tags: ios, iphone, .net-core, identityserver4, apple-sign-in

I am using AspNetCore 2.2.0 with IdentityServer4.

**Issue / Steps to reproduce the problem**
I am using IPhone for "sign in with apple". Tapping on the login button in the native app opens up a login webpage which is hosted at windows docker container. On the login web page, clicking on "sign in with apple" shows IOS native popup to continue with account already linked with the app or "Use a different Apple ID". When continue button is tapped, a white screen is displayed which freezes on appleid.apple.com and nothing happens.
[IPhone native popup-tapping on continue results in white screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJEYF.jpg)
Also, if the app is not linked with any apple ID before it works fine for the first time. On signing out and trying to login with the above steps, white screen appears. "Use a different Apple ID" flow works fine.
I am not sure whether there is any bug in my code or IdentityServer4. As per logs, callback /connect/authorize/callback is being received from Apple, but it does not reflect on the browser. Any help is highly appreciated.

**Relevant parts of the log file**
    trce: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator[0]
    ProcessInteractionAsync
    dbug: Equinox.Account.Services.EquinoxProfileService[0]
    IsActive called from: AuthorizeEndpoint
    dbug: IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultConsentService[0]
    Client is configured to not require consent, no consent is required
    dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint[0]
    dbug: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeResponseGenerator[0]
    Creating Hybrid Flow response.
    dbug: Equinox.Account.Repositories.PersistedGrantsRepository[0]
    MAbolcoMM9bi+QcW7FVOgryzkOBZXiPRZzpw4R1UAWk= not found in database
    dbug: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeResponseGenerator[0]
    Creating Implicit Flow response.
    trce: IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenService[0]
    Creating identity token
    dbug: IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService[0]
    Getting claims for identity token for subject: test@testmailid.com and client: mymobileapp
    dbug: Equinox.Account.Services.EquinoxProfileService[0]
    Get profile called for subject test@testmailid.com from client mymobileapp with claim types birthdate, family_name, gender, given_name, locale, middle_name, name, nickname, picture, preferred_username, profile, updated_at, website, zoneinfo, email, email_verified via ClaimsProviderIdentityToken
    dbug: Equinox.Account.Services.EquinoxProfileService[0]
    Issued claims: email, email_verified, family_name, given_name, locale, mosoid, nickname, oid, picture, preferred_username, shareid, trackingid, updated_at, userid, zoneinfo
    trce: IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenService[0]
    Creating JWT identity token
    trce: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint[0]
    Identity token issued for mymobileapp (no name set) / test@testmailid.com:             eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYmYiOjE1ODU5MDg5MjAsImV4cCI6MTU4NTk5NTMyMCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHNcdTAwM2FcdTAwMmZcdTAwMmZxYVx1MDAyZGxvZ2luXHUwMDJlZXF1aW5veFx1MDAyZWNvbSIsImF1ZCI6ImVxeG1vYmlsZWFwcCIsIm5vbmNlIjoiQ0IxXHUwMDI0OVx1MDAyM1x1MDAzZlpIUUp5N1U4IiwiaWF0IjoxNTg1OTA4OTIwLCJjXHUwMDVmaGFzaCI6InVLVWxcdTAwNW
    trce: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint[0]
    Code issued for mymobileapp (no name set) / test@testmailid.com: swsDKcMd78uWqcuqIA3h6KEk4v3GS1Ml
    info: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint[0]
    Authorize endpoint response
    {
    SubjectId: "test@testmailid.com",
    ClientId: "mymobileapp",
    RedirectUri: "mymobileapp://oauthredirect",
    Scope: "openid profile email offline_access"
    }
    trce: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint[0]
    End Authorize Request. Result type: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.Results.AuthorizeResult
    trce: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
    Invoking result: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.Results.AuthorizeResult
    dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerAuthenticationService[0]
    Augmenting SignInContext
    dbug: Equinox.Account.Repositories.PersistedGrantsRepository[0]
    8RotaoHQ32K7iyNlN61q0700M47i1Fx0 not found in database

**UPDATE**:
I am still struggling to resolve the issue. Upon further debugging, it turned out that when a custom endpoint "auth/apple" removes the auth cookie creation, the redirection is happening in the login page - it is obvious that without authentication the control goes to login page. Otherwise, the whitescreen appears. Below is the code snippet

```
AuthenticationProperties props = null;
HttpContext.SignInAsync(account.Username, account.Username, props).Wait();
```

What might be causing white screen due to auth cookie is quite surprising.
I would highly appreciate, if anyone can share any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved and white screen was shown due to Safari browser's security. Since the cookie was being created to my host login.mysite.com from appleid.apple.com. Although the cookie was being created (as seen in charles session) but the progress was blocked and white screen is shown.
I have created an intermittent invisible form and posted data into the flow from my domain and then continued the same step, which has resolved the issue.
Posting the resolution in case anyone faces the same issue with "Sign in with Apple" flow.